# SQL - Split Concatenated String into Columns after ;

Tags: sql, sql-server

I really need help with SQL. I have a database where you can find values like: abc;defg;hi and this is in just 1 column. So I wanna create 2 more colums which inserts the splited values.

**For example:**

Before:
Value01: abc;defg;hi

After:

```
Value01: abc,
Value02: defg,
Value03: hi
```

--Another Example would be this:--

Before:
Value01: abcd;efg;

After:

```
Value01: abcd,
Value02: efg,
Value03: null
```

So always 3 new values were created. I hope you understand my question!

Greetings

Comment: Can you please add the code you are trying to run? What database are you using? Can you provide a sample of the table structure and table data?

Comment: I cant give you the Database but it is MSSQL and the structure is like I mentioned, there are values in just 1 field which should be splitted in 3 other fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string_split()`:

```
select nullif(s.value, '')
from string_split(@value, ';') s
```

Comment: string_split does not guarantee the order of the values returned - and it returns the data in separate rows and not separate columns.  The OP wants to split the data out into separate columns.

Comment: @Jeff . . . We are reading the question differently.  My understanding is that there are three rows with one column each (which is how the results are presented).  But the question is ambiguous and the OP should clarify.

Comment: the OP stated they wanted to create 2 more columns and listed each column name and the value they wanted for that column.  Either way - string_split cannot be used reliably because it does not guarantee the order.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WITH`

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  [xml_val] = CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(SomeValue,';','</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
    FROM @yourTable
)

SELECT  [SomeValue] = col.value('.','VARCHAR(100)')
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY [xml_val].nodes('/t') CA(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that should be fairly performant:

```
 --==== Sample Data
Declare @testData Table (Value01 varchar(255));
 Insert Into @testData (Value01)
 Values ('abc;defg;hi'), ('abcd;efg;');

 --==== Solution using sample data from above
 Select *
      , Value01 = substring(td.Value01, 1, p1.pos - 2)
      , Value02 = substring(td.Value01, p1.pos, p2.pos - p1.pos - 1)
      , Value03 = substring(td.Value01, p2.pos, p3.pos - p2.pos - 1)
   From @testData                       td
  Cross Apply (Values (concat(td.Value01, ';;;')))              As v(Value01)   --Make sure we have delimiters
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(';', v.Value01, 1) + 1))       As p1(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(';', v.Value01, p1.pos) + 1))  As p2(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(';', v.Value01, p2.pos) + 1))  As p3(pos)      --End of string/element
```

You could also create a function that parses out the elements and then just call the function using cross apply.